# Sequelize Using Include and Attributes - Timeout Error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I receive a timeout error when I try to use attributes from my include model and I'm wondering if it is related to the way I am trying to include the attribute or an issue not related to my snippet of code.

Here is my route query (the db.Description, body is what I'm talking about):

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res, image){

    console.log(req.params.color);
    console.log(req.params.pattern);

    db.Images.findAll({ 
        where: {
            pattern: req.params.pattern,
            color: req.params.color
        },
        include: [{model: db.Description, attributes: 'body'}],
        attributes: ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource', 'description_id', 'description.body']
    }).then(function(image){
        //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/suit-result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
            })
        });
});
```

Here is my Images model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){

var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: DataTypes.STRING,
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    imageSource: DataTypes.STRING,
    description_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            Images.belongsTo(db.Description, {foreignKey: 'description_id'});
        }
    }
});
    return Images;
}
```

Here is my Description model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
    description_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    color: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
    return Description;
}
```

And here is where my join is happening:

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize("assistant", "admin", "pwd", {
    host: "site.com",
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});
var db = {};

db.Description = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/descriptionModel");

db.Images = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/imagesModel");

db.Images.associate(db);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: The attributes option should be either an array or an object (http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance).  If this is causing an error, you might see the timeout error from the client side.  But if you're watching the server for errors I'm not sure if this is it.  Are you able to see server side errors?  If so, what do they say?

Comment: @DJStroky it was a matter of putting the attributes in an array. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes option should be either an array or an object.  See the [docs](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance).